# socket.io errors when client connects

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have socket.io running successfully on my node.js installation.

```
info  - socket.io started
```

The console shows it running ok, but as soon as the client (browser) connects:

```
socket = io.connect('<my host>:8000');
```

The console is kicking out an error:

```
crypto.js:123
  return new Hash(hash);
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.createHash (crypto.js:123:10)
    at WebSocket.onSocketConnect (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:120:23)
    at WebSocket.handleRequest (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:71:10)
    at WebSocket.Transport (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transport.js:31:8)
    at new WebSocket (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket/hybi-16.js:59:13)
    at new WebSocket (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/transports/websocket.js:31:17)
    at Manager.handleClient (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:661:19)
    at Manager.handleUpgrade (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:618:8)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:123:10)
    at Server.emit (events.js:88:20)
```

can anyone understand what this might mean?

My code has been working fine on my local machine, its only when moving it to my production server does this error happen.

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: When you doing socket.send('my message')? You need to do .send when socket is connected. more info in http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: @minitech Node was only installed 2 days ago, so assume its the latest version.

Comment: @ncn I have edited the example code to show more context. I am waiting for the socket to connect before sending anything. Also, I should note that this code has been working fine on my local machine, its only when moving it to my production server does it stop working.

Comment: It might be good to check anyways — that’s probably the first thing to check when it works in one place but not another. Some tutorials and packages still install Node 0.6, for example.

Comment: @minitech Whoa, I'm running v0.5.11 apparently... I was under the impression I had a fresh install, but I think it might be running one that I installed a couple of years ago.

Comment: Also, I have realised that the error is actually happening as soon as the client connects, not when I send a message.

Comment: Try and see if this works on your production server: `node -e 'require("crypto").createHash("sha1")'`

Comment: Can you show the client side code as well, how you are sending the message 'onconnection'.

Comment: [Well, `Hash` is definitely defined in there now](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/crypto.js#L153) — and line 123 doesn’t return anything. Time for some bisection. :P

Comment: Found the commit that changed it, 5 months ago. So whatever’s on the server isn’t *quite* up-to-date either. https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/9901b69c8e372f39d6214fc0254b6465c4f329dc#L1L133

Comment: Ok great, I'm going to make sure I get the latest version now. I thought I managed that 2 days ago, but apparently the new install didnt overwrite the old one... I'll have to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's because Node was installed with the option --without-ssl. This means it doesnt install any of the crypto stuff, which was needed by socket.it. I installed openssl, reinstalled Node, and this fixed it :)